# Detecting hashed words and phrases to obscure them

Tags: python, regex, string

We have a list of "severe" words which we want to match and obscure against incoming sentences.

e.g.

```
words = ['shoots', 'forest floor', 'leaves']
sentence = 'The panda eats, shoots, and leaves on the forest floor.'
obscure(words, sentence)
=> 'The panda eats, s*****, and l***** on the f********.'
```

The difficult bit is that some of the severe words are so severe that we store them in a hashed format. So our annotators may input `shoots` but it is stored as `92415d1bb58ff22c1a98cb610bf0d774`. Then;

```
words = ['92415d1bb58ff22c1a98cb610bf0d774', 'forest floor', 'leaves']
sentence = 'The panda eats, shoots, and leaves on the forest floor.'
obscure(words, sentence)
=> 'The panda eats, s*****, and l***** on the f********.'
```

For single words (`shoots`) we can easily chop up the input sentence and match even the hashed words.

But multi-words (`forest floor`) is challenging. I have yet to figure out an elegant regex or iterative method for doing this.

Ideally we solve this in Python though JavaScript and Ruby are available to us if they have existing solutions or a large benefit.

Comment: If you can hash the words one by one, both in the input and in the blacklist, then you may be able to organize the blacklist so that you have three possible results: word is not in blacklist, word is "severe" by itself, word may be "severe" if followed by so and so. So e.g. you may have (the hash of) "forest" marked as "severe only when followed by (the hash of) floor". 
This could be done for instance with a dictionary with the starting words as keys, and a, possibly empty, sequence of the continuation words as values

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your input string by iterating over the `words` list until the string is empty, running replacements when matches are found:

```
from hashlib import md5
words = ['shoots', 'forest floor', 'leaves']
sentence = 'The panda eats, shoots, and leaves on the forest floor.'
def obscure(s, w):
   d = ''
   while s:
      if (k:=[i for i in w if s.startswith(i)]):
         d += (m:=max(k, key=len))[0]+('*'*(len(m) - 1))
         s = s[len(m):]
      elif (j:=[t for i in range(len(s)) if md5((t:=s[:i]).encode()).hexdigest() in w]):
         d += (m:=max(j, key=len))[0]+('*'*(len(m) - 1))
         s = s[len(m):]
      else:
         d += s[0]
         s = s[1:]
   return d

print(obscure(sentence, words))
```

Output:

```
The panda eats, s*****, and l***** on the f***********
```

This will also work with hashes:

```
words = ['92415d1bb58ff22c1a98cb610bf0d774', 'forest floor', 'leaves']
sentence = 'The panda eats, shoots, and leaves on the forest floor.'
print(obscure(sentence, words))
```

Output:

```
The panda eats, s*****, and l***** on the f***********.
```

Answer (score 0):

For not having the actual string in your code, you can still have a regex to match it, here is an example :

```py
import hashlib
import re

blacklist = [('92415d1bb58ff22c1a98cb610bf0d774', re.compile('\bs\w{5}\b'), "s")]
#            the hash                             a matching regex       the first letter


def censor(text: str) -> str:
    for hashed_value, regex, starting_letter in blacklist:
        for match in reversed(tuple(regex.finditer(text))):
            if hashlib.md5(match.group(0).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() == hashed_value:
                text = text[:match.start()] + starting_letter + ("*" * (len(match.group()) - 1)) + text[match.end():]
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(censor('The panda shines, eats, shoots, and leaves on the forest floor. '
                 'He has fashootsies from Shoots city.'))
    # The panda shines, eats, s***** and leaves on the forest floor. He has fas*****es from Shoots city.
```